# How to configure the logging module to log to stdout/stderr, a file and email?

Tags: python, email, logging, stdout, stderr

How to configure the logging module to send output `logging.INFO()`, `logging.ERROR()` etc to log stdout/stderr, a file and email at the same time?

Comment: You want an output log that contains the info, error, file and email all in one place? I assume you want this in a file log.  I think this is what you're looking for.  http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/logging/

Comment: I am looking for a way to send the same logging output to three location at the same time